(AMD Radeon Graphics) Should I download nvidia graphic driver
I have AMD graphics in my laptop. Then should I install nvidia graphic driver in ubuntu 24.04 LTS, If not then how to uninstall completely these installed nvidia driver, I have installed before nvidia-535

To remove all the proprietary nvidia packages run the following commands.
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get remove '^nvidia'
sudo apt autoremove 
sudo reboot

The drivers for AMD Radeon graphics are built-in  in Ubuntu 24.04, so you don't need to manually install these drivers.
On the other hand some computers have both integrated AMD graphics from the CPU and a discrete NVIDIA graphics card. In that case you should leave the proprietary NVIDIA graphics drivers installed in order to get the best performance from your NVIDIA graphics card.
If you are confused about whether your computer has an NVIDIA graphics card, then install the neofetch terminal program with sudo apt install neofetch and then use the command neofetch to run it. neofetch will show your computer's CPU and both GPUs if your computer has both an integrated and a discrete GPU.
